# How to display all objects that contain all item from array - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, map-function, filterfunction

Need for some help here. Looking for a hint to solve this issue :

The goal is to filter **arrayOfObject** and get all objects with the property **fruits** containing all the element from the given array.

```
  const arrayOfObject = [
  {
    id: 1,
    country: 'USA',
    fruits: ["APPLE", "ORANGE", "BANANA"]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    country: 'Canada',
    fruits: ["APPLE"]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    country: 'France',
    fruits: ["ORANGE", "BANANA", "LEMON"]
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    country: 'Mexico',
    fruits: ["BANANA", "PYTHON", "CHERRY"]
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    country: 'Ukraine',
    fruits: ["APPLE", "ORANGE", "CHERRY"]
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    country: 'Italy',
    fruits: ["APPLE", "ORANGE", "BANANA", "LEMON", "CHERRY"]
  }
];
```

**First exemple with this given array :**

```
const firstArrayOfFruits = ["APPLE","ORANGE","BANANA"];
```

**Should render =>**

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    country: 'USA',
    fruits: ["APPLE", "ORANGE", "BANANA"]
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    country: 'Italy',
    fruits: ["APPLE", "ORANGE", "BANANA", "LEMON", "CHERRY"]
  }
]
```

**Second exemple with this given array :**

```
const secondArrayOfFruits = ["APPLE","ORANGE"];
```

**Should render =>**

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    country: 'USA',
    fruits: ["APPLE", "ORANGE", "BANANA"]
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    country: 'Ukraine',
    fruits: ["APPLE", "ORANGE", "CHERRY"]
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    country: 'Italy',
    fruits: ["APPLE", "ORANGE", "BANANA", "LEMON", "CHERRY"]
  }
]
```

Comment: you can use simply map/forEach here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
const arrayOfObject = [{
    id: 1,
    country: 'USA',
    fruits: ["APPLE", "ORANGE", "BANANA"]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    country: 'Canada',
    fruits: ["APPLE"]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    country: 'France',
    fruits: ["ORANGE", "BANANA", "LEMON"]
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    country: 'Mexico',
    fruits: ["BANANA", "PYTHON", "CHERRY"]
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    country: 'Ukraine',
    fruits: ["APPLE", "ORANGE", "CHERRY"]
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    country: 'Italy',
    fruits: ["APPLE", "ORANGE", "BANANA", "LEMON", "CHERRY"]
  }
];

const firstArrayOfFruits = ["APPLE", "ORANGE", "BANANA"];

var arr = arrayOfObject.filter(item => item.fruits.filter(fruit => firstArrayOfFruits.indexOf(fruit) + 1).length >= firstArrayOfFruits.length);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: it is not good enough to test the length of the arrays are equal, you need to check that an item.fruits contains all of the firstArrayOfFruits. eg `item.fruits.sort().join(',').includes(firstArrayOfFruits.sort().join(','))` should do it.

Comment: Note that I've filtered the `fruits` to remove any elements that are not present in `firstArrayOfFruits`, so if the two arrays are of equal length *after* filtering out those elements, then they would definitely contain the same elements. The `join` procedure won't work if the order of elements is different among the two arrays. It is also better to use `>=` instead of `==` to account for possible duplicates in `fruits`.

Comment: yea you are right, i see that now. my apologies

Comment: nesting 2 filters isn't a best practice

Comment: In terms of performance, yes you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Using ES6 some() function is useful because when finds an entry it will return true and doesnt check the rest, so you can save some calcs, time and CPU

```
const filtered = arrayOfObject.filter(obj => {
       if(obj.fruits.some(fruit => fruitsLisToCheck.includes(fruit)))
         return obj
    })

const fruitsLisToCheck = ['BANANA', 'APPLE'];

const arrayOfObject = [
  {
    id: 2,
    country: 'Canada',
    fruits: ["APPLE"]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    country: 'France',
    fruits: ["BANANA"]
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    country: 'Mexico',
    fruits: ["CHERRY"]
  },
];
```